# How to check the values in each row of last column in a table?

Tags: javascript

Just want to ask how to check the values in each row of last column in a table?

here is the figures that i am trying to solve.

thanks In advance

Comment: here is the fiddle that i am trying to solve
http://jsfiddle.net/heliosSuperman/CZg96/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the solution

```
$('#sumcomputation >tbody >tr').each(function(i,data){

$(this).children(':last-child').css('border','1px solid RED');
var val = $(this).children(':last-child');
alert($(val).children('input').val());

});
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CZg96/39/

Comment: just want to ask how to get the text in td; 

i am trying to use .text() but doesn't work
$('#sumcomputation >tbody >tr').each(function(i,data){

    $(this).children(':eq(3)').css('border','1px solid RED');

Comment: you can use .html() instead of text, and if you want to append then use append();